# Can hard braking destroy a well maintained automatic transmission?

Tags: transmission, braking

What would actually break and more importantly how?

I've been told by a mechanic today that this is something he has seen before but I cannot figure out what would actually cause the transmission to break.  I found a small tidbit on Mister Transmission stating [abrupt stops could damage drivetrain components like transmission mounts](https://www.mistertransmission.com/best-ways-to-destroy-your-transmission/), but there isn't any explanation offered as to how that damage could occur so I'm still not sure *why* the transmission mounts would be damaged.

Would using much grippier tires than stock affect this?

Comment: High shock loadings break things.

Comment: "Can hard braking destroy a well maintained automatic transmission?" No, this is nonsense.

Comment: Front wheel drive car?  Certainly really hard frequent breaking will induce additional loads on transverse engine mounts. But with that said I’d certainly expect a robust testing procedure to protect the customer for that.  But who’s to say why any part wears out?  Parts are warrantied for given mileage/ age. Beyond that stuff happens. Its all in the statistics and variability.  Stuff wears out. Things break. It happens. Thats why this question forum exists.  Make/ model / mileage?